# Terraform: Azure Logic Apps plan type Consumption

Tags: terraform, azure-logic-apps, terraform-provider-azure, consumption

I'm trying to build a configuration file in Terraform to create a logic app with plan type Consumption (Multi tenant).

[image: Attached the plan images for reference]

I can find for resource "azurerm_logic_app_standard" However, I'm not able to achieve it as there aren't any Terraform resources available for azurerm_logic_app consumption

Please assist me with a solution

Comment: You have to use `azurerm_logic_app_workflow` to create consumption plan logic app . and then create the workflow by creating triggers etc.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Ansuman Bal you need to use `azurerm_logic_app_workflow` in order to create a consumption plan. Below is a sample that you can refer to.

> ```
> resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "sample" 
> {
>  name                = "workflow1"
>  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
>  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
> }
> ```

For more information you can refer [azurerm_logic_app_workflow](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/logic_app_workflow)